# PHP Content not loaded from MySql, but no error

Tags: php, mysql, archlinux, material-design-lite

I am working on some sort of blogging platform in php with a nice material design lite frontend. However I have a page that dynamically loads the content, it works fine in the root directory, but not in my admin directory. I hope you can spot some kind of error/typo in my code, I know the error is in the menu-start file, since disabling it enables loading.

[Here](http://hastebin.com/jovavinora.php) is the page that loads the code
and [here](http://hastebin.com/seyeciluzi.xml) is the menu-start page

If you need any other code, please ask

Comment: show your code  .. not link

Comment: post your code in the question and not an external link please, [*grazie!*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grazie)

Answer (score 1):

You're using relative links for include, which will mess up when you start changing directories. Use a pseudo-absolute path with `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. Be sure to use this for all of your includes.

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/menu-start.php'; ?>
```